# How to call a javascript function from a textbox when the textbox is not null / some value is passed into the textbox

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a situation where I have a textbox which will be updated with some value and as soon as the textbox gets its value a javascript function will be called. I have tried something but this not working

```
if (validSubmission) {
    User user = new User(); 
    String StatusMessage=user.executeUserTask("_create_","",userBusinessEmailId,userPassword,cityOfBirth,userFirstName,userLastName,userCompanyName,userCompanyAddress,userPhone,"");
    if(StatusMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?retMessage="+"Account created sucessfully");
    }
    else {
        //response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?retMessage="+StatusMessage);
        responseMsg = "Invalid Domain Entry";
        {%>
            Redirect();
        <%}
    }
}
```

This is the text box where I am getting the value

```
<input type="text" id="keyToShowInvalidDomain" name="keyToShowInvalidDomain" value="<%=responseMsg%>" onchange="Redirect()">
```

This is the function which I am trying to call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        alert($("#keyToShowInvalidDomain").val());
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: define *not working* please

Comment: @Cid Redirect not working

Comment: @Cid  i am trying to pick the value of the textbox using  the id  but i think {%>
              Redirect();
          <%} is not working

Comment: Put your jQuery codes inside `$(document).ready(function(){  //Your code should be here  });` and include `jQuery` library too

Answer (score 0):

For input type text onchange event will not work try to use **onkeyup** or **onkeydown**

```
<input type="text" id="keyToShowInvalidDomain" name="keyToShowInvalidDomain" value="<%=responseMsg%>" onkeyup="Redirect()">
```

Comment: Redirect() is not called

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        alert($("#keyToShowInvalidDomain").val());
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="keyToShowInvalidDomain" name="keyToShowInvalidDomain" value="<%=responseMsg%>" onchange="Redirect()"> 
</body>
</html>
```

You are using selectors based on jQuery so you need to add jQuery library to your page. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#keyToShowInvalidDomain').change(function(){
        // Call redirect function
    });
}
```

Above code should work with JQuery.